# MySQL using 'not in' list with wildcards issue

Tags: mysql, wordpress

i am writing the following SQL statement using my existing wordpress db as a learning environment...

```
Select
  wp.ID,
  wpum.user_id,
  wpp.post_name
From
  wp_users As wp Left Join
  wp_usermeta As wpum
    On wp.ID = wpum.user_id Left Join
  wp_posts As wpp
    On wpum.user_id = wpp.post_author
Where
  wpp.post_status = 'publish' and
  wpum.meta_key = 'nickname' and
  wpp.post_name not in ('sample%', 'hello%')
order by
    wpp.ID desc
```

As you can see I have used alias's for my tables and filtered my results of the word press posts to be only 'published' posts and only selecting the nickname to avoid duplicate results by user_id.

My issue is the wildcards do not appear to do anything.. my results are as returned with the sample & header posts still showing.

However, this would work as:

```
Select
  wp.ID,
  wpum.user_id,
  wpp.post_name
From
  wp_users As wp Left Join
  wp_usermeta As wpum
    On wp.ID = wpum.user_id Left Join
  wp_posts As wpp
    On wpum.user_id = wpp.post_author
Where
  wpp.post_status = 'publish' and
  wpum.meta_key = 'nickname' and
  wpp.post_name not like  'sample%' and 
  wpp.post_name not like 'hello%'
order by
    wpp.ID desc
```

My output is with the desired results removed.. anybody able to help me out? The second example is perfectly usable... I would just like to know my alternatives to learn good practices.
I've tried googling and using a few examples, but not having much luck.

Thanks all

Apol's if my post is wrongly formatted or this has been answered before, again I have searched!

Comment: Your second version is the correct way to do it. `IN` and `NOT IN` do exact matching, wildcards are only matched with `LIKE` and `NOT LIKE`.

Comment: If you have working code and you're looking for advice on how to write it better, codereview.stackexchange.com is the place to post. SO is for help fixing problems in code.

Comment: Barmar - thanks for your responses. I had seen some various other examples, but as mentioned... none of those appeared to do what I was after.
I was more worried about execution time when this becomes larger, especially on a networked WP instance with multiple sites.

Thanks anyway

Comment: It's definitely going to be slow. I don't think `NOT LIKE` can take advantage of an index, so it has to do a full table scan. But the network isn't an issue, all the work is done on the database server.

Comment: oh how far I have come >_<